# where can i see joomla site code i have build

Tags: php, joomla

I want to know where is the code of my site that i have build in joomla. i want to modify a dynamics string at my homepage.

Comment: You don't know where your own site's source code is?

Comment: i m nil in joomla want to modify using php code

Comment: i want 2 know which code is where?

Comment: what are you talking about? Please clarify what the problem is. Joomla is a huge system. What part do you want to modify?

Comment: i just want to replace a string in site but can't find file. this string is showing at home page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have access to a ftp account on your web host? If so the files of Joomla would be in the root directory of where Joomla is installed.

Comment: i have searched in root directory. its not there. joomla structure is different.

Comment: download all file from ftp and search in downloaded folder using Notepad++

Comment: Notepad++ can search a string into all files of a directory